# How to get Stock Summary by passing date range in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table `Stock`:

| Id | OpeningQty | OpeningRate | CurrentQty | CurrentRate | ConsumedQty | ProductId | OpDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 4 | 100 | 6 | 20 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 5 | 500 | 2 | 500 | 3 | 25 | 2022-01-20 |

So I am trying to get all the columns of stock table by passing date range but the `OpeningQty` should be `currentQty` (`closingQty`) for next day and next day so on.

I tried:

```
select 
    Id,
    OpeningQty, 
    OpeningRate,
    CurrentQty,
    CurrentRate,   
    ConsumedQty,
    ProductId,
from 
    Stock
where 
    convert(date, OpDate) between '2022-01-18' and '2022-01-23'
```

I don't know how to get.

Comment: `convert(date, OpDate)` Why? Is that column NOT defined as a date datatype? And you did not identify your expected output based on your sample data. Do you expect a row for every ProductId and date in your date range? Seems odd that you don't even select the date column in your query. Lastly, "I don't know how to get" is not a meaningful comment. No one should need to guess (though some will). All reasons for a downvote.

Comment: Expected output would help also

Comment: @Charlieface So I am trying to get all the columns of stock table by passing date range but the OpeningQty should be currentQty (closingQty) for next day and next day so on.

Comment: There is no need to take it out on @SMor , I also don't understand what your expected output should be. "the OpeningQty should be currentQty (closingQty) for next day and next day so on" doesn't hold any meaning for me, and clearly others feel the same. Please paste in *actual expected output* into your post, in other words a table similar to the sample data you have provided, showing what results you want. We're all happy to help, just please be clear as we're not mind-readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lag()` window function to access "previous" rows in a partition.

```
SELECT id,
       lag(currentqty, 1, openingqty) OVER (PARTITION BY productid
                                            ORDER BY opdate) AS openingqty,
       openingrate,
       currentqty,
       currentrate,
       consumedqty,
       productid,
       FROM stock
            WHERE opdate >= '2022-01-18'
                  AND opdate < '2022-01-24';
```

And don't use casting and `BETWEEN` for your condition on the point in time. Use a half open range with the *next* day (or hour, or minute, or ...) as upper boundary. That way you don't have to cast, which can render indexes useless and don't have to worry when the precision increases.